# Angular $location search does not work always

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'm having a problem I can't seem to understand why it is happening:

I have an angular app where one of the routes is defined in the route provider as

```
 .when('/pageA/:item1', {templateUrl:xxx, reloadOnSearch:false})
```

I have a service function which in turn is using the following code:

```
var targetUrl = '/pageA/'+item1;
$location.path(targetUrl).search('item2',item2Val);
```

The problem is that if the user is at a page with a location different than pageA, the url is correct and I Can see both values, item1 and item2. However, if the user is already at pageA and there iis only a change in item1 and item2, the resulting url does not include the search object item2.

Can anyone explain this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to catch the change in url, even in the same page, set `reloadOnSearch` to `true`

Comment: perhaps I did not explain myself correctly. when already at pageA and using the same mechanism to switch to another item1 AND item2, the resulting URL shown in the address bar only shows the /pageA/item1 without the search parameter. changing the reloadOnSearch to true did not help in this case. the redirection occurred already when it was set to false, but the search parameter is ommitted.